# How to authenticate/Authorize the MVC web app and web api in the same application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

We have developed a web application using asp.net MVC framework with Azure active directory for Authentication/Authorization.
Now the question is we are going to use api in that webapp. For authenticating web api can we use same the request token which we get when we the authorize successfully for the webapp web app.

Thanks,
Tamilselvan S.

Comment: Is the issue was fixed? If not, please feel free to let me know with step you were blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple authentication middle ware for the web app supports OWIN. To support both cookie and bear authentication, you can refer the code below:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
        Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {

        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = Authority,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
            {
                // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example)without having to change settings
                // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },

            AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
            {
                // Suppress the exception if you don't want to see the error
                context.HandleResponse();

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

        },
        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
        }

    });
```